# What formulaic character to use?

Tags: arithmetic

Imagine you wanted to express a very general thought as a formula. Said thought would basically presuppose the existance of a variable x and that some sort of calculation would occur with it. But what kind of calculation or value is going to be used, would still be unclear.

Do you know of a formulaic character that expresses: "insert any basic elementary arithmetic symbol and another value here" for example: "+y" or "-z"?

Comment: How about "$\setminus $square", $x \square y $

Comment: Thank you. That seems quite reasonable!